# How can I call setstate from another function without breaking ruls . react js

Tags: reactjs

I have **setstate** in a **file** and when i import this file and call this **setstate** then the error of **breaking** **ruls** shown to me:

```js
export function Profile() {
    
    const [openContact, setopenContact] = useState({open:false, color:''})
}
```

```js
import Profile from '../Profile';


function Apps(props){
  return(
      <div>
        <img src={contact} alt='contact' className='iconapps' onClick={Profile.props.setopenContact({open:true})} />
       </div>
      )
  }
```

Comment: Hooks must be used in the body of a functional component, not implemented in external functions.

Comment: Given the code you posted, `Profile` has no `props` property, and even if it had, that property wouldn't magically have a `setopenContact` property just because use used a state hook. If you assumed it should be so, you need to revisit basic javascript and react learning materials.

Answer (score 1):

You can try rendering the **img** tag inside **Profile** component. Then import and render **Profile** component in **Apps** component. This way, you will call **setState** method inside **Profile** component, which will not prompt any error.

Answer (score 0):

that mean thiere is not any methode to call it without api like redux or something else ...